# How to run alter query to modify mysql database using hook_schema?

Tags: hooks

I want to change data-type of a field in for a particular table in database. I  want to use hook_schema_alter() to do so.
The ALTER query is:

```
ALTER TABLE `abcd` CHANGE `session_number` `session_number` INT( 255 ) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Session number to get number.'
```

Is it possible to implement such query using hook ? If yes please guide me.
Tonnes of thanx in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't do that in `hook_schema_alter()`. `hook_schema_alter` is to alter the schema definition but it won't be able to modify the database for you. You need to implement that in `hook_enable()` which will invoke during enabling your custom module.

Comment: I have multiple instances for same code means same project running for 2 different places . Thats why am thinking to use hook_schema_alter(). Moreover, how to user hook_enable to implement db alteration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you are having single Drupal code base for multiple sites. I assume that you only want one of the sites having schema change. So you need a separate module for altering schema.

You need to implement `hook_schema_alter()` and `hook_enable()` in .install file of your custom module.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_enable().
 */
function mymodule_enable() {
  // other_module is the module name which define the schema of 'abcd' table.
  $schema = drupal_get_schema_unprocessed('other_module', 'abcd');
  db_change_field('abcd', 'session_number', 'session_number', $schema['fields']['session_number']);
}

/**
 * Implements hook_schema_alter().
 */
function mymodule_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  $schema['abcd']['fields']['session_number'] = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'size' => 'tiny',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'default' => 0,
    'description' => 'Session number to get number.',
  );
}
```

Please note that `'size' => 'tiny'` means 1 byte size for integer type. More details can be found [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/159605).

Comment: Code is same for multiple sites. I want to run it on each site. Huge thankx...

Answer (score 2):

Changes to the schema are typically handled with [hook_update_N](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7.x) and you will normally locate this file in the `module.install` file.

For example with the update from Drupal 6.x-7.x the some of the base permissions were rename:

```
/**
 * Rename blog and forum permissions to be consistent with other content types.
 */
function system_update_7000() {
  $result = db_query("SELECT rid, perm FROM {permission} ORDER BY rid");
  foreach ($result as $role) {
    $renamed_permission = $role->perm;
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )create\ blog\ entries(?=,|$)/', 'create blog content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )edit\ own\ blog\ entries(?=,|$)/', 'edit own blog content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )edit\ any\ blog\ entry(?=,|$)/', 'edit any blog content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )delete\ own\ blog\ entries(?=,|$)/', 'delete own blog content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )delete\ any\ blog\ entry(?=,|$)/', 'delete any blog content', $renamed_permission);

    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )create\ forum\ topics(?=,|$)/', 'create forum content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )delete\ any\ forum\ topic(?=,|$)/', 'delete any forum content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )delete\ own\ forum\ topics(?=,|$)/', 'delete own forum content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )edit\ any\ forum\ topic(?=,|$)/', 'edit any forum content', $renamed_permission);
    $renamed_permission = preg_replace('/(?<=^|,\ )edit\ own\ forum\ topics(?=,|$)/', 'edit own forum content', $renamed_permission);

    if ($renamed_permission != $role->perm) {
      db_update('permission')
        ->fields(array('perm' => $renamed_permission))
        ->condition('rid', $role->rid)
        ->execute();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is true for database tables the module itself defines. If a module wants to change the database tables defined from another module, it should implement `hook_schema_alter()`.

Comment: For my own knowledge going forward, would this hook also by best kept in the `module.instal`l file? and how many times will the `hook_schema_alter` hook run?

Comment: Drupal looks for `hook_schema_alter()` in the .install file of the module. It is called every time a module calls `drupal_get_schema()` and Drupal cache for that has been cleared, for example because a module was disabled or enabled.

Comment: I think you are correct with the use of `hook_schema_alter` to manage the changes in `$schema`, but the actual `db_change_field` call should be handled within `hook_install` or `hook_update_X` as these hooks allow for better deployment management. A module should not have be disabled/enabled for updates/changes take effect.